# Alternate of Proc SQL case statements in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have been able to do the desired with the following code.
But i have a large data set and i want to do the same using SAS Data step code and Not Proc SQL.
Following is the code:

```
`proc sql;
create table RTA_NDP_Red_2 as 
select TRFFIC_NO as TRAFFIC_NO,

sum( case when ticket_date_v1 between '01OCT2019'd and '30SEP2020'd  then 1
          else 0 end) as NDP_vio_cnt_t1,
sum( case when ticket_date_v1 between '01OCT2018'd and '30SEP2019'd  then 1
          else 0 end) as NDP_vio_cnt_t2,
sum( case when ticket_date_v1 between '01OCT2017'd and '30SEP2018'd  then 1
          else 0 end) as NDP_vio_cnt_t3,
sum( case when ticket_date_v1 LT '01OCT2017'd   then 1
          else 0 end) as NDP_vio_cnt_t4

from  public.RTA_NDP_Red_1
group by TRFFIC_NO;
quit;
run;`
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `by` grouping in the data step will generate two temporary variables：`FIRST.varibles` and `LAST.varibles`.

And if a conditional statement is true,the value will be Assigned as 1.If a conditional statement is false,the value will be Assigned as 0.

If you grasp all above,then what you desired is a piece of cake.

```
proc sort data=public.RTA_NDP_Red_1;by TRFFIC_NO;run; 
data RTA_NDP_Red_2;
    set public.RTA_NDP_Red_1;
    by TRFFIC_NO;
    if first.TRFFIC_NO then call missing(of NDP_vio_cnt_t1-NDP_vio_cnt_t4);
      NDP_vio_cnt_t1+('01OCT2019'd<=ticket_date_v1<='30SEP2020'd);
      NDP_vio_cnt_t2+('01OCT2018'd<=ticket_date_v1<='30SEP2019'd);
      NDP_vio_cnt_t3+('01OCT2017'd<=ticket_date_v1<='30SEP2018'd);
      NDP_vio_cnt_t4+(ticket_date_v1<='01OCT2017'd);
    if last.TRFFIC_NO then output;
run;
```

Hope it helps